# CloudWatch Metric based on extracted value from Log Message

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to extract some field from a log message (only a string, not JSON) and then display them via a metric in a nice graph showing the averages.

The log message looks like this: `Replication of data was successful [userId=f25b8eb7de56f6a3, latencyMs=21ms]`

I've read the documentation about [Filter and Pattern Syntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html) but I couldn't get it to work.
Played around with the space separation e.g. `[..., latency=*]` but this just gives me `$latency = 'userId=f25b8eb7de56f6a3, latencyMs=21ms'`.

Most probably this is not even possible only with metrics?

Any help is appreciated.